# Gaps in Squarefree numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

The density of squarefree numbers is well known.

I am wondering about the squarefree numbers in $[2,n]$ namely the second and higher moments of the gaps. Is anything known about these?

Comment: Since there are asymptotically $\frac{6}{\pi^2}n$ squarefree numbers in the interval, the average gap is going to have length $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. The second moment is definitely a more interesting question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A number of authors e.g. Hooley, Filaseta, Trifonov have considered this problem of moments of gaps between square-free numbers.  For example, [Filaseta and Trifonov](http://people.math.sc.edu/filaseta/papers/distribpaper.pdf) (paper in Proc. London Math. Soc. (1996); see Theorem 4) showed that for all $0\le \gamma < 43/13=3.30769\ldots$ one has 
$$ 
\sum_{s_{n+1}\le x} (s_{n+1}-s_n)^{\gamma} \sim B(\gamma) x, 
$$ 
for some constant $B(\gamma)$.  Here $s_n$ denotes the $n$-th square-free number.