# Maximal gaps between squarefree numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

In this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291864/gaps-in-squarefree-numbers),  I asked for the moment statistics of the gaps in squarefree numbers which got an immediate and excellent answer by @Lucia.

The answers to two questions  in mathstackexchange demonstrate that for any $k>0,$ there are infinitely many sequences of consecutive integers where the Mobius function is constant (resp. all nonzeros). These answers use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

**Question:** What are the best known lower bounds to the maximal gap in squarefree (resp. squarefull) numbers in the interval $(1,n]$?

Comment: This question came up earlier on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149194/consecutive-non-squarefree-integers/149198#149198